# Password change reminder Ubuntu

Tags: linux, password, encryption

I have an encrypted hard drive on my Linux box. When it was ready for me to change my password because of the 60 day expiration I ran into a problem. I changed the password and once I shutdown my computer for a while and turn it back on an hour or so later I was no longer able to login because the encryption. Long story short I had to unwrap my encrypted hard drive and update it with the new user login password. My question is what's the command to use to warn you day(s) before your password expire so you are able to change your password before time expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the passwd command to do this

```
passwd -w 10 user
```

This will warn the user starting 10 days before their password change is required

> -w, --warndays
>
> WARN_DAYS
>              Set the number of days of warning before a password change is
>              required. The WARN_DAYS option is the number of days prior to the
>              password expiring that a user will be warned that his/her password
>              is about to expire.